# Volume of a solid

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have some doubts about this exercise: compute the volume of the solid defined by the following inequalities:
$0 \leq x \leq 2$,$\quad 4-x^2 \leq z \leq 1-y^2$.

I've set a triple integral:

$V= 2\int_{0}^{1} \left (\int_{0}^{1-y^2} \left ( \int_{2}^{\sqrt{4-z}}dx \right )dz \right ) dy=2\int_{0}^{1} \left (\int_{0}^{1-y^2}\left ( \sqrt{4-z}-2 \right ) dz  \right ) dy $

after some calculation I've found $\frac{7}{3}-\frac{9}{4} \log 3$.
Is it correct?